# Punctuation for 'and therefore', 'and as a result' etc when they don't introduce an independent clause

Tags: punctuation, commas, adverbs

I have seen similar questions regarding 'and therefore' when it introduces an independent clause, and the favourite seems to be '..., and, therefore, ...' to punctuate without making 'therefore' the start of a new sentence.

How does this apply when it doesn't introduce an independent clause? There should be no need for a comma before 'and', but in cases where the following part is very short, surely adding commas around 'therefore', 'as a result', and so on would upset the flow?

As an example:
'Becoming curious about people's hobbies helps us connect and therefore care more.'

Comment: If *helps us connect and care more* expresses the essential meaning of the sentence, then insert *therefore* between commas. Otherwise, leave the commas out. In other words, use parenthetical commas if you are expressing nonrestrictive (additional) information; don't, if you aren't. Personally, I don't see the word as being restrictive—it's more an afterthought, so I would use commas. Actually, I'd omit it entirely. I don't think it's needed at all. (But that's just my opinion.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you, that's very helpful!